# how can i use async pipe when I'm using graphql queries?

Tags: angular, graphql, subscription, apollo-angular, async-pipe

I have an angular project and in my component, I fetch data with graphql and in HTML I show an image of the result. but for a moment, I get this error in the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined
```

this is my html code:

```
<div
[style.background-image]="
'url(http://localhost:1337' + (data.article.image.url )+ ')'
"
>
</div>
```

and in my component i have:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.queryArticle = this.apollo
.watchQuery({
  query: ARTICLE_QUERY,
  variables: {
    id: this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id")
  }
}).valueChanges.subscribe(result => {
  this.data = result.data;
  this.loading = result.loading;
  this.errors = result.errors
});
}
```

now, how can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the `async` pipe, I think you need to use the safe navigation operator.

Put this in your HTML (add the question marks):

```
<div
[style.background-image]="
'url(http://localhost:1337' + (data?.article?.image?.url )+ ')'
"
>
</div>
```

It will basically ensure that data exists, then article exists inside of data and that image exists inside of article.

Learn more about the safe navigation operator [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-to-safe-navigation-operator-in-angular-2/).

There is a way to use the `async` pipe but I see you `subscribe` to the observable and you set values for `data`, `loading`, and `errors` and it will involve more work to get those properties with the `async` pipe.